# Compare function for lists

Tags: python, python-2.x, sorting

I need to sort a list of lists. The following is a `compare` function:

```
def compare(lhs, rhs): # lhs&rhs are lists
    delta = len(lhs) - len(rhs)
    if delta > 0:
        return 1
    elif delta < 0:
        return -1
    if lhs < rhs:
        return 1
    elif lhs > rhs:
        return -1
    return 0
```

It looks pretty wordy. Is there a way to rewrite the function without performance penalty?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you want to sort lists by their length first, and then by "whatever lists are otherwise sorted by". I also assume that you want to pass your function as the `cmp` argument to the `list.sort` or `sorted` function.

You can do this in both a more natural to read, and computationally more efficient way, by using the `key` argument instead:

> In general, the *key* and *reverse* conversion processes are much faster
>   than specifying an equivalent *cmp* function. This is because *cmp* is
>   called multiple times for each list element while *key* and *reverse*
>   touch each element only once.

(Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)

This should be the appropriate `key` function for your case:

```
def length_first(lst):
    return len(lst), lst
```

Or simply:

```
lambda lst: len(lst), lst
```

Example:

```
>>> from random import randrange
>>> lists = [[randrange(5) for _ in range(randrange(3, 6))]
...          for _ in range(10)]
>>> print '\n'.join(map(str, sorted(lists, key=lambda lst: (len(lst), lst))))
[0, 0, 4]
[2, 3, 0]
[2, 4, 0]
[3, 4, 2]
[4, 1, 4]
[1, 0, 1, 0]
[2, 0, 1, 1]
[3, 1, 0, 4]
[0, 0, 0, 3, 2]
[4, 0, 1, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you (+1). Actually, for my `compare` function `sorted(lists, cmp=compare)` matches to `sorted(lists, key=lambda lst: (-len(lst), lst), reverse = True)`

Answer (score 2):

mkrieger1's answer is preferable. But Python2 has the [`cmp`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#cmp) keyword which allows you to simplify your code.
Ignoring the `delta` part of your function the last three `return`s would become one.

```
def compare(lhs, rhs):
    delta = len(lhs) - len(rhs)
    if delta > 0:
        return 1
    elif delta < 0:
        return -1
    return cmp(rhs, lhs)
```

You can actually simplify it even further.
You don't need to return 1 or -1 you just have to return a non-zero that is either positive or negative.
This means you can use:

```
def compare(lhs, rhs):
    delta = len(lhs) - len(rhs)
    if delta:
        return delta
    return cmp(rhs, lhs)
```

You can actually 'simplify' this further by using `or`,
this is as `or` returns the lhs if it is true otherwise the rhs.

```
def compare(lhs, rhs):
    return (len(lhs) - len(rhs)) or cmp(rhs, lhs)
```

Just to note `or` is lazy and so `cmp(rhs, lhs)` will only run if `(len(lhs) - len(rhs))` equals zero.

Again using `key` is preferable, the above is just ways you can improve your function.